# Detect changes of Framework Elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a class with a `PreviewGotKeyboardFocusEvent`, this event is triggered in the right way. But I want the `OnPropChanged` to be triggered when changes are made in the `currentFrameworkElement`. `currentFrameworkElement` can be of different Controls for example `TextBox`, `CheckBox`, `RadioButton` etc. When the user for example toggles a `CheckBox` or enters text in a `TextBox`I want to trigger `OnPropChanged`. How can I do this, what is the best way to do it? At the moment `OnPropChanged` is triggered when the `Tag` of `currentFrameworkElement` changes but this has to change obviously.

```
internal sealed class KeyboardInputEvents : InputEvents
{

    public KeyboardInputEvents(DispatcherEvents dispatcherEvents) : base(dispatcherEvents)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), UIElement.PreviewGotKeyboardFocusEvent, new KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(GotKeyboardFocus), true);
    }

    private void GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentFrameworkElement = ((FrameworkElement)e.NewFocus);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(currentFrameworkElement.Name);
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(FrameworkElement.TagProperty, typeof(FrameworkElement));
        desc.AddValueChanged(currentFrameworkElement, OnPropChanged);
    }

    private void OnPropChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Changes were made, do something
    }


}
```

Comment: There is already a function you can override: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.onpropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @o_weisman can you point me to an example or show me an example?

Comment: @o_weisman any ideas?

Comment: Actually my suggestion does not address your issue, it's relevant only for controls you inherit from. Not sure there is a way to get notified for every property of any control, but you can use the method shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863207/wpf-receiving-property-value-change-notification-for-properties-of-a-framework?rq=1 for specific properties that are of interest

Comment: @o_weisman I already found that I want to get notified if the value of a control changes, it seems not to be possible with the DependencyPropertyDescriptor.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't work for specific control properties when you replace `FrameworkElement.TagProperty, typeof(FrameworkElement)` with for instance `Control.TextProperty, typeof(Control)` ?

Comment: `Control.TextProperty` gives me an error: `Error 'System.Windows.Controls.Control' does not contain a definition for 'TextProperty'`

Comment: Sorry, I gave an example that used a Winforms property. You can try any other control property such as NameProperty, TagProperty etc. This will also most likely work for specific type of controls and their properties.

Comment: @o_weisman I tried NameProperty and TagProperty this worked but I need the text (value).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105217/discussion-between-o-weisman-and-sybren).